# Foundation tabs hover background color

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation and need to change default background color, font color and color on hover. I have tried something like this but it is not working for me:

My css file:

```
.tabs {
  background-color: #353A41;
  border: 0;
}

.tabs a{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.tabs :hover{
  background-color: #2A2E34;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
.tabs :hover {
  background-color: #2A2E34;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
.tabs a:hover {
  background-color: #2A2E34;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your custom CSS:

```css
.tabs a{
    background: colorname;
    color: colorname;
}
.tabs-title > a:focus, .tabs-title > a[aria-selected='true'] {
    background: colorname;
    color: colorname;
}
```